# Is the Asian version of Watch_Dogs censored?

Tags: watch-dogs

An apparent pricing mistake by an online retailer allowed me (and others) to pick up Watch_Dogs for $4 recently. However, some people suggested that it was the Asian version of the game and that the Asian version is censored. I purchased it in the US, got a UPlay code and activated it on UPlay, installed it and it runs without issue. Everything is in English and there is no obvious sign that it's anything other than the regular version. So my questions are:

1. Do I have the Asian version? How would I tell?
2. Is the Asian version censored?
3. If yes to #2, how is it censored? What's missing?

Comment: No solid answer on anything really, but I seriously doubt an Asian version would have everything in English.

Comment: Where did you find the "suggestion" that it was an Asian version of the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have the Asian version? How would I tell?

The Asian version only supports English audio and English+3 Asian languages for the subtitle.

From [Steam page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/243470/) seen by users living in Asia,

> Notice: Purchases made in this region will only receive English, Japanese, Korean and Traditional Chinese subtitles with English audio.

even though the language boxes on the right mentions otherwise (15 languages, no Asian languages at all).

---

> Is the Asian version censored? If yes, how is it censored? What's missing?

I can't really tell since I don't buy or play the game, but according to [a Steam player from Taiwan](http://steamcommunity.com/app/243470/discussions/0/540744936844206427/#c540744936850912620),

> Let me explain the whole thing to you,
>
> For most Asian, they don't know the Watch_Dogs they bought is a censored version. At least they censored:
>
> 1. Nude girl in some scene (by adding bra for them)
> 2. Change the score of killing civilians in Spider Tank mode from +500 to -500
> 3. Blood effect
>
> It is censored to obey the CERO law in Japan. (Ubisoft just picked one with the most strict law to obey so they can publish single Asian version)
>
> The problem is, the release date of Asian version is one month later than worldwide one, and the most important is NONE of the retailer or Ubisoft mentioned it is a censored one during the preorder period. The non-censored contents is not restricted in all Asian countries. However, the censored information was leaked and people at least here in Taiwan is angry.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The fact that I have a whole bunch of European languages available would suggest that I do not have the Asian version.